# MainWindow opens twice (StartupUri, App, Loadscreen)

Tags: c#, xaml, mainwindow

I've got a problem with my application. I selected my Loadscreen.xaml as the "StartupUri" in my App.xaml. The Loadscreen.xaml.cs contains a progressbar, that runs until 100% - than it closes and opens the MainWindow. The problem is, that it opens the MainWindow twice after closing the Loadscreen. What is my fallacy?

App.xaml:

```
StartupUri="Loadscreen.xaml"
         Startup="Application_Startup">
```

Loadscreen.xaml.cs:

```
public void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar_Ladebalken.Value = i;
        label_Titel.Content = i + "%";
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;

        if (i < 100)
        {
            i += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            i = 0;
            Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
            Timer.Stop();

            Window W = new MainWindow();
            W.Show();

            this.Close();
        }
```

public void Application_Startup:

```
public void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        bool Absicherung;
        Mutex Mutex = new Mutex(true, this.GetType().GUID.ToString(), out Absicherung);

        if (Absicherung)
        {
            Window W = new Loadscreen();
            W.Closed += (sender2, args) => Mutex.Close(); ;
            W.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(FM_Mutex_Meldung, FM_Mutex_Titelleiste, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            Mutex.Close();
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're opening two instances of `Loadscreen`:

- One with `StartupUri="Loadscreen.xaml"`
- The other one from `Application_Startup` which is called because of `Startup="Application_Startup"`.

Just get rid of `StartupUri="Loadscreen.xaml"` and the problem should be gone.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But so, the MUTEX does not work anymore. If I run the application one more time, there is no error message that says that the application is already running.

Comment: @Exception You did remove `StartupUri` and keep `Startup`?

Comment: Yes. But it seems to work now... I'm just trying to fix some things. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Amazing answer, had been searching for hours because I kept getting this stupid null reference somewhere in mscorelib defaultbinder... kept throwing that error after I added 2 services in constructor through DependencyInjection. I  was looking at the wrong place I guess because the problem was that the StartupUri was pointing at a constructor of mainwindow.xaml without those injection probably.. removing that line fixed it. So Happy! Thanks!